# SQL: позиция конца произвольной подстроки

Tags: sql, mysql

В таблице есть записи типа

```
katalog/2 40 140 141 1042 14344 41456 42567
katalog/40 140 141 1042 14344 41456 42567
katalog/140 1042 14344 41456 42567
katalog/1042 14344 41456 42567
и т.д
```

Для своих целей пытаюсь вытащить цифры первые после слеша.
Запрос типа:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`src`, 9, Length(`src`))
FROM `url_alias`
WHERE `src` LIKE 'katalog/%'
```

Возвращает все цифры разом.

**Подскажите, как в SUBSTRING передать позицию перед пробелом, при неизвестном количестве цифр между слешом и первым пробелом?**

Насколько понимаю, это можно сделать регулярными выражениями, но не представляю как это сделать.

P.s. извините за название :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать таким образом:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( SUBSTRING_INDEX( `src` , ' ', 1 ) , 9 )
FROM `url_alias`
WHERE `src` LIKE 'katalog/%'
```

Или даже так:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( `src` , ' ', 1 ) , '/', -1 )
FROM `url_alias`
WHERE `src` LIKE 'katalog/%'
```

Но все-таки какие-то сложные манипуляции, лично я предпочитаю делать на уровне PHP.

А по поводу регулярок, я бы так сказал: "Иногда у программиста появляется проблема и, почесывая затылок, он думает: "*Ну, тут я применю регулярку...*". И с этого момента, у него появляется уже две проблемы"

Comment: за две проблемы плюсанул бы ещё раз :)

Comment: Согласен, что это перебор. Но захотелось попробовать что-нить новое.